# No sound notification in KDE Plasma Desktop

Tags: 14.04, indicator-sound, kde4, plasma

I installed the KDE plasma desktop yesterday on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. The environment has been working quite well up until now.

However, I just noticed that there was no Sound notification icon in the panel.

Although the sound seems to be working, it's very faint. Even after adjusting the volume from System Settings->Notifications->Player Settings and increasing it to 100% the sound remains faint.

How do I restore the notification area sound indicator and fix the volume problem?

P.S. This problem is only on the KDE environment. Sound is working just fine on GNOME.

Comment: Is kmix installed?

Comment: @hal7df No it wasn't. I had installed only plasma-desktop which doesn't even include the bare essentials like sound manager and network manager. Installed kde-desktop and problem solved.

Comment: Okay. Good to see that that was the problem. Just so you know, if you end up installing KDE on a system that didn't originally come with KDE, you should install the `kubuntu-desktop` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that kmix is installed.

Just so you know - if you want to install KDE on a system that didn't come with it, it is best to install a transitional package like `kubuntu-desktop`, `kde-standard`, or `kde-full`. This way you don't have to worry about missing components.

Answer (score 7):

Starting Plasma 5.4 the new `plasma-pa` package [was introduced to replace kmix](http://davidrosca.blogspot.com/2016/04/audio-volume-improvements-in-plasma-57.html).

Remove kmix, install `plasma-pa` and restart `plasmashell` to see changes:

```
sudo apt-get remove kmix
sudo apt-get install plasma-pa
killall plasmashell
plasmashell &
```

Answer (score 0):

I had lost my visual notification when turning my volume up/down right after an upgrade. After reading this I saw that kmix was no longer installed. I took a shot in the dark and decided to see if it would let me install it on top of plasma-pa, and voila! Literally 3 seconds after the completion of apt installing kmix I tapped my volume buttons and the visual notification was back! No complaining from apt that plasma-pa was already installed it just installed kmix alone and BOOM, my volume meter is back..

HTH anyone who had a similar issue.

Karl Haines